# Laravel NotAllowed

Tags: php, laravel

This is error says. Im inserting an static value for now in controller to check if the controller is okay. the code is below

```
    protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
        {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
        }



//IM JUST inserting static value for now to be able to check if inserting
DataController

    public function update(Request $request, $name=null)
    {
        $insert = new leave([
        'bio_id'                    => '10258',
        'vacation_balance'          => '25',
        'sick_balance'              => '25'
        ]);
        $insert->save();

        return view('pages/admin/data');
    }


Route   web.php

Route::post('admin/pages/admin/data', 'Admin\DTRDataController@update');

data.blade.php

    <form action="{{url('admin/pages/admin/dtrdata')}}" method="post">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
    <input type='text' class='total_undertimes' name='total_undertimes' id='total_undertimes' style='width:70px' />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit" />

    </form
```

What is ther error in my code

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

line from your view. This makes your FORM submitted as PATCH method.

FYI:
methodNotAllowed exception throws when request using wrong method.
Ex:) When u POST to URL that is configured as GET in your Route file. In your situation you are requesting POST url using PATCH method.

Answer (score 0):

You are showing the route for the URI `admin/pages/admin/data` but your form is going to `admin/pages/admin/dtrdata`. I am not sure what that 'dtrdata' URI is but it doesn't accept the `PATCH` method.

`admin/pages/admin/data != admin/pages/admin/dtrdata`

Answer (score 0):

Your Form Url and route are different :

```
route : admin/pages/admin/data
 form : admin/pages/admin/dtrdata
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do two correction in your code.

1. your Form Url and route are different :

   - route url : admin/pages/admin/data
   - form_url : admin/pages/admin/dtrdata
2. methodNotAllowed this error you got because you have submit form using patch method and you define post method in route. so should be used

   `Route::patch('admin/pages/admin/data', 'Admin\DTRDataController@update');`

   instead of

   `Route::post('admin/pages/admin/data', 'Admin\DTRDataController@update');`

Answer (score 0):

Route::patch('admin/pages/admin/data', 'Admin\DTRDataController@update');